# Why is Chrome ignoring text input's "size" attribute?

Tags: html, google-chrome

The following size attribute has no effect whatsoever. Why?

```
<input type="text" size="80" placeholder="blablabla bla lba bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla lba">
```

It's defaulting to 60 characters and there's seemingly nothing I can do to change that.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you have some styling affecting it. Without any style rules, it [works just fine](http://jsbin.com/ubeqoj). But when you apply a style rule with a smaller size, [that takes precedence](http://jsbin.com/ubeqoj/2).

To figure out what style rule is affecting it, right-click it and choose "Inspect Element," then look at the styling information shown to the right.

Comment: If that were true, I could add an inline style that would over-ride the global style, right? But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `textarea` element instead of the `input` element:

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="1" style="overflow: visible" placeholder=
"blablabla bla lba bla bla bla blabla bla bla bla lba"></textarea>
```

This produces more consistent, though not completely consistent rendering. The setting `overflow: visible` is there to make IE reserve room for 80 characters, otherwise only 79 will fit, due to vertical scroll bar.

Why does the problem appear with `input`:

The attribute `size="80"` sets the visible width of the field to the “average” width of 80 characters. This is not exactly defined (what “average”?), and browsers implement it even illogically: using `size="80"` tends to give considerably less width than 4 times the default width of 20 characters. So the browser isn’t even consistent. The proportion depends on the font and on the browser. (This happens on other browsers as well.)

If you need to keep using `input`:

You could use `style="width: 80ch"`, but not all browsers support this CSS3 feature, and there is no guarantee that it has been implemented properly. The `ch` unit is by definition the advance width of the digit zero, '0', which is in most fonts the same as the advance width of digits in general. (E.g., Firefox almost correctly implements this. Almost, but not quite.)

You could set the font in the `<input>` elements to some monospace font. This does not remove the issue, but it makes the widths closer to the specified widths.

Comment: note: `placeholder` attribute is also new in HTML5. To adopt placeholder feature, fill in the textarea & remove the contents once editing starts, via JavaScript.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor, the `placeholder` attribute is a distinct question, please do not confuse the issue with it. What you suggest does not address the question asked but creates several problems, and the `placeholder` attribute was introduced to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

As of Google Chrome 26 on Mac OS Lion, the "ch" unit isn't supported.

Upon an element inspected with inline style "width: 16ch", the style is marked as "Invalid property value". Other common units (pt, px, em, %) are accepted fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering why you can **enter** 60 characters, the property that determines that how many characters is called **maxlength**:

> **Maxlength**
>
> If the value of the type attribute is text, email, search, password, tel, or url, this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters (in Unicode code points) that the user can enter; for other control types, it is ignored. It can exceed the value of the size attribute. If it is not specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. Specifying a negative number results in the default behavior; that is, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. The constraint is evaluated only when the value of the attribute has been changed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Size only determines the width in characters, not the amount users can enter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after trying a lot of other solutions, I fixed this by adding a width to the input fields.

```
input {
    width:90px; /* Your width may vary */
}
```